# Why and where is the `/tmp` directory size limited in VSCode Devcontainers?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

#### Pre-Text

I am executing a scientific simulation inside a VSCode devcontainer (source here [1](https://github.com/ldimbenchmark/LDIMBenchmark/blob/main/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json)).
The program I am running creates a big (13G) file and writes it to the `/tmp` directory.

Unfortunately, the `/tmp` directory is only 11G big (middle of the screenshot[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvolf.jpg)). which results in `Out of space` Exception.

[image]

#### My Questions:

1. Why is `/tmp` limited by 11G?

It seems to be a `tmpfs` volume because as the file is written my RAM usage increases (left of the screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvolf.jpg)).
Normally when I execute a container the `/tmp` directory is not directly visible in `df -h` which I suppose means it is part of overlay (and thus only limited by the space of my harddrive)?

2. Where is `/tmp` mapped to `tmpfs`?

I couldn`t find any information regarding that. My goal is to turn it off and just use a normal overlay. Is it maybe one of the devconainer extensions?

#### Other things I've tried so far:

There is no volume mapping to `/tmp` in docker when I inspect it:
[image]

I tried to reproduce it by installing one extension at a time and it seems like `docker-in-docker` is adding the `/tmp` directory:
[image]

Comment: Can you write to another directory, like one mounted via the `-v` Docker option?

Comment: That would be one workaround and in fact I am currently circumventing it by mounting a volume to `/tmp`. But I would still be interested in why its using my RAM in the first place.

Comment: Seems to be docker in docker: https://github.com/devcontainers/features/issues/471